Erasure Error Correction Protocol in Kah Jen Wo's Thesis
Referring to this thesis (download at bottom of page): https://repository.tudelft.nl/record/uuid:649f5fe9-0266-4be2-a3a5-4b5ffd13073e
In section 4.2, I understood things quite well up to Table 4.1. After that, the author introduces a protocol to simplify the erasure correction by repositioning the lost qubit during syndrome measurement. Although I mechanically understand the process itself and have a rough grasp of how this is working (though not fully comprehend it), some questions remain:

How can we just reposition the lost qubit? Aren't stabilizers made
for the particular encoding? Would cycling the logical qubit
positions still make things work fine?

The author doesn't seem to have rigorously proved this mechanism in
this paper. Has it been done in some other paper (seems unlikely as
there's no reference), or is this just too trivial to prove?

MOST IMPORTANTLY, is this a general protocol that will work for all
stabilizer QEC codes? Like if, for the [[7,1,3]] (Steane) code, I
use K = (k mod 7) + 1 and rework Table 4.2 (pretty simple if I just
think of it as D1 loss and find the errors), will it work?


I really need the last question answered for my work - please help guys. Thanks in advance!
PS. The paper uses [[5,1,3]] code. Here are some pics for easier access.



I'm the author of the thesis. Many thanks for showing interest in my thesis. I'll answer your questions one by one.
To answer the first part, let me first explain how we can know which of the 5 qubits is lost. In my protocol, the 5 qubit states correspond to the output of 5 photon detectors, where we use dual-rail encoding for our photons -- meaning the qubit states are encoded in either the temporal or spatial modes of the photon, rather than the presence of photons. Therefore, we can know if a photon is "lost" simply by noticing that one of the photon detector is not triggered. This lets you know which photon is lost -- I called this heralded erasure in my thesis. Now, let me get to your questions below.

How can we just reposition the lost qubit?
Aren't stabilizers made for the particular encoding? Would cycling the
logical qubit positions still make things work fine?

It is not necessary to physically "move" or "swap" the qubits, because you can instead mathematically rewrite the stabilisers to have the same effect. How much "cycling" is needed depends on the outcome of the heralded erasure.

The author doesn't seem to have rigorously proved this mechanism in this paper.
Has it been done in some other paper (seems unlikely as there's no
reference), or is this just too trivial to prove?

If by "this mechanism", you're referring to heralded erasure, then I hope that my answer above already cleared your doubt. Otherwise, let me know what exactly you're still unsure about.

MOST IMPORTANTLY, is this a general protocol that will work for all stabilizer QEC codes? Like if, for the [[7,1,3]] (Steane) code, I use K = (k mod 7) + 1 and rework Table 4.2 (pretty simple if I just think of it as D1 loss and find the errors), will it work?

I did not check rigorously myself whether this works for all stabiliser quantum error correcting codes, but I don't see why not. I cannot answer directly and rigorously whether "it will work" or not -- this you would have to do yourself -- it is just some simple linear algebra exercises. If you are still unsure how to approach this checking part, let me know and I can give some hints.

Woah, never did I expect the author himself to find and answer this post. Thank you so much!
I'm actually working on a project based on your thesis - but for different Stabiliser codes like [[7,1,3]], [[11,1,5]], etc. I've made really good progress for the Steane code, but the erasure correction part still eludes me (there's a serious lack of literature about this online, especially for constructing the syndrome table for erasures).

If a particular qubit (say D1) is lost, then in my understanding we should focus on non-trivial errors involving D1. What then is the basis/principle for your "pairing" of syndrome ECs (D1/2, D3/4)? I also didn't understand the last line of Table 4.1's caption; e.g. why are X2, Z2, Y2. accepted as correction for D1 loss?
I believe if I understand this part, I'll have a clearer view of the correction using permutations.

The erasure correction table is something I computed myself using linear algebra. In particular, I used Mathematica, but I'm sure this can be done in any other programming languages like Python in case you don't have access to Mathematica.
To answer your question regarding Table 4.1's 0001 syndrome measurement: the reason for X2 as the correction is because a D1 erasure + an X-Pauli error on D2 gives 0001 syndrome.
However, a D1 erasure + an X-Pauli error on D5 also gives the same syndrome. It is simply not possible to distinguish these cases, so I just put X2 in the table.

Assuming uniform distribution across all Pauli errors, by correcting for X2 everytime you measure 0001 syndrome is the same as correcting for X5 in terms of mitigating error rate.

The "pairing of syndrome ECs (D1/2, D3/4)" is something I found to be true via numerics for the [[5,1,3]] QEC code. I can't be 100% sure if this pairing is possible for other codes. You'd have to write code to check for [[7,1,3]], for example.

I finally understand... you're considering one additional Pauli error on a non-lost qubit. I also looked up this recent paper of yours (https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.07224) where you clarified this in the Methods: Erasure-error correction section.
However, if I may ask, why use this methodology for erasure correction? Couldn't you use "2-qubit correction involving the lost qubit" for all syndromes? Is there a particular reason to consider additional Pauli error on a non-lost qubit?

The only reason for considering the additional Pauli errors on non-lost qubits is simply because of completion's sake, i.e., otherwise my erasure correction table is simply just the 0000 syndrome.
I cannot use a "2-qubit correction involving lost qubit" because of theorem 4.2.1 -- i.e., you can at most correct for 2 erasures for the [[5,1,3]] code. So indirectly, I cannot correct for 1 erasure + 1 pauli error fully because then that would mean we're performing better than what is stated in theorem 4.2.1.
Hope that makes sense!

Sorry for the delayed response. I've finally understood the erasure correction scheme and made progress in my project. Thanks for all your guidance and help!
